# How do you debug GWT apps?

Tags: java, debugging, gwt

As my GWT app gains complexity, it's nearly impossible to debug.

I am using Eclipse + Google plugin. Hosted mode is super slow and freezes, browsers are prompting that javascript is dead ... It takes impossibly long time to find bugs for me now ..

Is there some sort of workaround for debugging? Thanks

Comment: How big is your app? AFAIK Dev Mode should be sufficiently fast to use if the app is reasonably small, or split up using code splitting. Other than Dev Mode your only hope with debugging is log statements or `Window.alert()`

Comment: I've used hosted mode with my app before with no problems - is your project big or is there a certain part of it that's causing it to slow down so much in hosted mode?

Comment: It isn't very large :/ Very slow thing is mail server, but I wrote unit tests for that what needn't be used every time is commented out. Another slow thing is Hibernate, but I have quite tiny database with not very lot of data ...

Comment: I do have some kind of problem. But my problem is related the serialization, serialization at dev mode is deadly slow.. Your bottleneck also could be serialization..

Comment: Well I am selecting blobs from database and serialising them, but that's in count of  tens, not even a hundred ... But true is, app is much slower since I added more data, I think Hibernate slows it somehow ... somehow terribly :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We split our projects into as small modules as possible, and we test them separatelly. Modules are splitted into smaller independent components. If we want to debug our component we attach it directly to the RootPanel and we use Dev mode.

If we need to debug our component in the module or in app we attach it to the RootPanel the whole module panel or project panel.
If app is rather small we use Dev mode, but in bigger apps we compile it with 1 permutation and we deploy it into Tomcat.

Comment: Me too, deploying for Chrome and Firefox and deploying to Tomcat, my eclipse breakpoints are somehow magically hit even when running from tomcat ... well sometimes

Comment: I should add this: Chrome is much, MUCH slower in development mode then Firefox right now.